# How do I use additional CSS to change opacity on individual images in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, class

I've added images to a page by uploading them to the image library of Wordpress.

I'm wanting to make it so that when I hover over an image the opacity changes.

I've found some code to do this, and that it needs to be added in the additional CSS section of editing the Wordpress theme.

When I enter the code, however, it applies the opacity change to all images whereas I only want this to apply to a couple of images.

I have gone into the images and given them unique classes to reference, but what is the code to then reference these classes when inputting the additional CSS?

```
img.hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Thanks Kate

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732627/how-do-i-reference-additional-css-to-a-single-image-in-wordpress-instead-of-all) your closed question. It will get you a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: @AlonEitan I was asked to revise and repost, which I have done.